# не могу установить tensorflow, используя virtualenv, впрочем как и без virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, установка, virtualenv

пишу в консоли: `(env) C:\Users\User>pip install tensorflow`

выдает:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/6c/c1f6bc2ca251c627976acae937f4f27f7349300e2b69b711e47b092d2642/tensorflow-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.1 (from tensorflow)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/wrapt/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DBC8E696A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/wrapt/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DBC8E69710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/wrapt/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DBC8E69C18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/wrapt/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DBC8E697B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/wrapt/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wrapt>=1.11.1 (from tensorflow) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wrapt>=1.11.1 (from tensorflow)
```

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить `timeout`, как я советовал Вам в [прошлом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1113991/339283).

Comment: Помогло увеличение `timeout`?

Comment: да, спасибо большое!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связана с проблемами в сети.

Увеличьте `timeout`:

```py
pip install --default-timeout=1000 tensorflow
```